# Wifi module for Zumo robot

Tags: arduino, wifi

I'm a CS student trying to implement a clustering algorithm that would work for a set of robots in an indoor controlled environment. I'm still starting on Robotics and don't have much experiencing in figuring out what will work together.

My plan is to get 6 of these [Zumo robots](https://www.pololu.com/product/3126) and plug in a wifi module like the [Wifi shield](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1491). Then, I would use this to do inter communication and execute my algorithm.

My question: Can the wifi module just be plugged in and would it work? If not, how can I go about achieving this task. I see lots of Arduino boards with different names and I'm not sure which works with which, and whether they can be plugged in. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to determine if the Zumo is Arduino shield pinout compatible.

It appears the Zumo has a compatible microcontroller. This likely means that you would be able to use the Arduino IDE, compiler and libraries to program your robot.

If the Zumo is not pin compatible, you may want to investigate the ESP8266 range of SoCs. They're a microcontroller that can be programmed with the Arduino IDE, and have built in wifi. They're also very light and cheap.

The easiest way to integrate the ESP8266 with the robot may be to use their respective serial connections. When integrating 3rd party components onto your robot ensure that you are using the correct voltage (5V vs 3.3V). If components run on different voltages you may need to use a level shifter.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this. Maybe I should try the polulu forums.

Comment: That's probably a good idea